# cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'exceptionType' is not allowed to appear in element 'throwException'

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to throw exception on camel. I am on version 2.2.170.redhat-000013. When I use below code in spring DSL

```
<throwException id="_throwException1" exceptionType="org.mycompany.MyException" message="Test Exception"/>
```

Gives

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'ref' must appear on element 'throwException'.
- cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'exceptionType' is not allowed to appear in element 
 'throwException'.
- cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'message' is not allowed to appear in element 
 'throwException'.
```

Schema location in my project is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd" >
```

throwException syntax should work as per documentation, please help to find mistake.

Comment: There is no such Camel version, can you correct this, eg is it 2.17 or what version?

Comment: Also as you are using Red Hat Fuse, you can use the vendor customer portal to get help and support with their product

Comment: Camel version is 2.18.1

Comment: Are you getting this error when you deploy and run this in Fuse or how do you get the error? Also make sure your XML file is correct, as it smells of some error somewhere.

Comment: This is run time error. And I dont see any XML formation related error any where. If I use bean ref instead of exceptionType in throwException. It is working as expected.